# Partition of a set induced by an equivalence relation

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory

Let $X = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\} × \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}$ and define $R$ on $X$ by $(x_1, y_1)R(x_2, y_2)$ if $x_1 + y_1 = x_2 + y_2$.

Determine the partition of $X$ induced by $R$.

I have already shown that this is an equivalence relation. I am trying to figure out what this means when it says, the partition of $X$ induced by $R$.

The way that I understand it, $x+y = \{2,3,...,10\}$. So would I be listing the equivalence classes of each possible value that $x+y$? I am very confused about this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you give an example of one or two sets you *think* you'd include in the partition? The overall idea *seems* right, but the last paragraph is a bit hard to decipher.

Answer (score 1):

Given some set $X$ and $R$ an equivalence relation on it, what is partitionned is what is called technically the *quotient set* noted $X/R$ of $X$ by $R$, that is the set of *all* distinct equivalence classes which can be generated from any element of $X$ with the relation of equivalence.

Consider $R$ as being represented by some binary graph also noted $R$, some subset of $X\times X$. $(x,y)\in R$ meaning $x$ and $y$ are equivalent modulo $R$. For $R$ to be an equivalence on $X$ it has to be represented by an equivalence graph:

(1) $R$ is reflexive  $\forall x\in X\ (x,x)\in R$
otherwise stated the diagonal of $X\times X$ belongs also to $R$.

(2) $R$ is symmetrical, i.e. it does not differ from its symetrical graph noted $R^{-1}=\{(y,x)\ s.t.\ (x,y)\in R\}$ otherwise stated $(x,y)\in R \iff (y,x)\in R$.

(3) $R$ is transitive, $R=R\circ R$ the compound graph being defined by $R\circ R=\{(x,z)\ s.t.\ (\exists y)[(x,y)\in R \wedge (y,z)\in R]\}$ otherwise stated $(x,y)\in R \wedge (y,z)\in R \Rightarrow (x,z)\in R$

Now consider one element of $X$ and consider its image $R(\{x\})$ noted 
$R(x)$ for short i.e. the set of all elements corresponding to $x$ by the relation: $R(x)=\{y\in X \ s.t.\ (x,y)\in R\}$. It is some cut in the graph $R$ for some  fixed $x$ abscissa along $y$ ordinates which is called the class of equivalence of $x$ and is also noted $[x]_R$. $x$ is said to be one representant of the class $[x]_R$ which is a subset of $X$. Now the quotient set $X/R$ is nothing else than the union of all these equivalence classes $X=\bigcup_{x\in X} R(x)$. By construction it is easy to show that two distinct equivalence classes have no element in common: if $x$ and $y$ are not equivalent then $[x]_R\cap [y]_R=\emptyset$. Hence the quotient set $E/R$ can be seen as a disjoint union, i.e. a partition of $X$ into equivalence classes.

What you have to do in your particular example is to find for each ordered pair $x\in X$ its equivalence class $[x]_R$ i.e. the set of all other ordered pairs (including $x$ itself) equivalent to $x$. Then select among these classes only those which are distinct. By symetry you can generate all the equivalence classes considering only half of your elements in $X$ as representants.

$(1,1)\quad [(1,1)]_{R}=\{(1,1)\}$

$(1,2)\quad [(1,2)]_{R}=\{(1,2),(2,1)\}$

$(1,3)\quad [(1,3)]_{R}=\{(1,3),(3,1),(2,2)\}$

$(1,4)\quad [(1,4)]_{R}=\{(1,4),(4,1),(2,3),(3,2)\}$

$(1,5)\quad [(1,5)]_{R}=\{(1,5),(5,1),(2,4),(4,2),(3,3)\}$

$(2,5)\quad [(2,5)]_{R}=\{(2,5),(5,2),(3,4),(4,3)\}$

$(3,5)\quad [(3,5)]_{R}=\{(3,5),(5,3),(4,4)\}$

$(4,5)\quad [(4,5)]_{R}=\{(4,5),(5,4)\}$

$(5,5)\quad [(5,5)]_{R}=\{(5,5)\}$

Answer (score 0):

If $X$ is set then a partition of $X$ is a collection $(S_i)_{i \in I}$ of non-empty subsets $S_i \subseteq X$ such that $X = \bigcup_{i \in I} S_i$ and these subsets are pairwise disjoint, i.e. $S_i \cap S_j = \emptyset$ for $i \neq j$. In other words, each element of $X$ is contained in exactly one of the $S_i$.

If $(S_i)_{i \in I}$ is a partition of $X$ then this induces an equivalence relation on $X$ via $x \sim y$ if and only if $x$ and $y$ are contained in the same $S_i$.

On the other hand every equivalence relation on $X$ also induces a partition of $X$ via the correspondings equivalence classes (because every elment of $X$ is contained in exactly one equivalence class.)

These two constructions are inverse of each other, so equivalence relations on $X$ are, in the above way, the same as partitions of $X$.

So the exercise is to give the equivalence classes of $X = \{1, \dotsc, 5\} \times \{1, \dotsc 5\}$ with respect to the equivalence relation $(x_1, y_1) \sim (x_2, y_2) \iff x_1+y_1 = x_2+y_2$. For example, the equivalence class of $(2,3)$ is $\{(1,4),(2,3),(3,2),(4,1)\}$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you want to list the equivalence classes.  The set of equivalence classes is the partition induced by the equivalence relation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are on the right track. An equivalence class is a subset of $X$ that only contains elements that are equivalent to each other under $R$. In this way we can partition (group together elements of) $X$ into disjoint subsets that are each an equivalence class, grouping together equivalent elements of $X$.

In your case each equivalence class  contains elements of $X$ whose components add up to the same number. You already found the possible sums: $\{x+y| (x,y) \in X\} = \{2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10\}$

So one subset defined by the partition of $X$ induced by $R$ is the subset of all $(x,y) \in X$ such that $x+y =2$: $\{(x,y) \in X | x+ y = 2\}$

So you are being asked to find a subset of $X$ for each $n \in \{2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10\}$: $\{(x,y) \in X| x+y = n\}$

Together, the definitions of each subset (you could define each subset by just listing the elements contained within it) describes the partition.